# What game asks "who is most likely to..."?

Tags: identify-this-game

There is a board game popular amongst students at my university back in the mid 90's that I am trying to identify.

What I remember (or think I remember) about it is that there was a stack of cards asking questions about "who is most likely to" do a certain thing.  Everyone then voted who amongst the game players is "most likely" to do what was on the card.

Everyone has some sort of token they use to select someone else in the game.  Once everyone has voted they reveal their picks.  I think if you voted along with the majority you got to move your token forwards on the board.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This one sounds like "Point Out", which you can find here:

http://www.glopgame.com/who-is-the-most-likely-with-Truth-game.php

However, there isn't any mention of a board or tokens. So, its probably a modern variant on what you've described.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the game you are looking for is [Imaginiff](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2750/imaginiff).

> The game is played in rounds. Each round, one of the players is chosen
> as the "subject" of a question. The question has 6 multiple choice
> answers. The question is read aloud and players vote on the answer
> they think is correct. Points are awarded to the players that chose
> the most popular answer.

An example of a question:

> Imaginiff  were a flying object. Which would he/she be?
>
> 1. Blimp
> 2. Biplane
> 3. Glider
> 4. Frisbee
> 5. Lear jet
> 6. Brick

It is at least, the most similar game I know to what you are describing.

Comment: This seems to be the inverse of the question's game: the question described a game which denotes a quality and you voted for a person, Imaginiff denotes a person and you vote for a quality. Does Imaginiff have a variant that puts things the other way around, or is there a related game which does that?

Comment: @doppelgreener I know it is not exact. But memory being what it is, if the OP can't remember the name of the game, chances are he might not remember the game exactly. So there is a probability that this is the game he is looking for, and if not it might be a bread crumb that leads to the right one.

Answer (score 0):

[True Colors](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/514/true-colors) seems to be the closest match to what you are describing, though the party game market is so full of clones that your basic description could probably work for many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be *[A Question of Scruples](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1748/question-scruples)*, which I remember being popular in the mid '90s indeed?

Each player is dealt five (yellow) cards with moral dilemmas, along with a single red card with an answer on it — either Yes, No, or Depends.
They must then ask the question on one of their five cards to a player who is most likely to give the answer on their answer card.

If the answers match, both the question and the answer card are discarded and a new answer card is drawn (but not a new question card), otherwise both a new question and a new answer card are drawn.
The player to first empty their hand (of question cards) wins, so there are no tokens to move on a board.

Read more on [Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1748/question-scruples) or on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scruples_%28game%29).