# Identify a card game where players are asked questions about life situations

Tags: identify-this-game

Loved playing a board game back in early 90s. On your turn, you would pick a card which asked various questions on life situations. Then you had to pick someone playing who you thought the card would best apply to.

Examples:

- Who's most likely to commit murder.
- Who's most likely to have an affair.
- Who's the kindest person here.

Everyone else playing had to make their guess and then you would read out your choice. Made for a lot of debate.

Loved it and would love to try and find it again but cannot remember what it's called. Can anyone please help? Thanks all.

Comment: Could it be one of the ones mentioned [here](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/27806/)?

Comment: Why would this question be marked as a duplicate of /27806 when the criteria are different?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming this game an English-language party game printed in the United States, because that's what I know best, but variants of the "who would X" mechanic have been published for decades in many countries.  That said, searching BoardGameGeek for party games with social mechanics (particularly voting on other players) and limiting the list of games to those published in the USA from 1970 to 1999 gives four likely candidates:

[True Colors](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/2094176/true-colors) (1990):  Cards show a question, and you vote on who best fits it - and try to bet how many players will choose you.  Questions are things like "WHO would still clip coupons after winning five million dollars in the lottery?" and "Flirting is an art, WHO is the undeniable expert?"  Has been published under other names and in several art styles, the link shows the box and components from the 1990 Pressman edition.  Closest match in mechanics and publication date.

[The Ungame](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/2094176/true-colors) (1973):  This roll-and-move "board game" is more about explaining yourself to other players or discussing other players.  Questions include "Talk about a happy marriage." and "Share a childhood experience with death."  Not the closest match for mechanics or publication date, but it sold like hotcakes so worth mentioning.

[Family: The Game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/146588/family-game) (1990):  A board game about dealing dirty laundry about family members, questions include things like "When it comes to smelly feet, our family's champion would have to be _____!"  Not a very popular game and it doesn't use cards, but it's otherwise a very close match for mechanics.

[Who Said That?](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/6413/who-said) (1998):  A card-based board game, everyone writes an answer to a question like "You're in a bar and find a wallet full of money, what do you do?" and you try to guess who gave what answer.  Close match in mechanics but published a few years after the "early 90s."

Speaking personally, this is also how most of my games of Nomic and 1000 Blank White Cards end up, but neither game has set cards.

Answer (score 3):

In **[A Question of Scruples](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1748/question-scruples)**, each player is dealt several cards which pose ethical questions, along with a single answer card (YES, NO, DEPENDS). The goal is to be the first to empty your hand of question cards.

The question cards pose a range of hypothetical scenarios, in the general format of "You find a wallet with £50 in it. Do you keep the money?"

On a player's turn, they pick a question in their hand and try to choose who to ask in order to receive the answer written on their card. If it does, the asker discards the question card; if not they replace it with a new one.

After the answer, the asker or other players have the opportunity to challenge the answer. If so, the challenger presents an argument as to why the target's answer would have been a different one, and the target has a chance to rebut it. The rest of the table votes, and the winner of the challenge passes a question card to the loser.

For example, if the target answered NO, the asker (or another player) could challenge, arguing that the answer should instead be DEPENDS; "If there wasn't ID in the wallet I don't think you'd try to find out who owned it." To this, the target responds, "If I couldn't tell whose it was I'd turn it in to the police." The remaining players then vote on who should win, based either on which they think is more likely from their knowledge of the player, or on whose argument was better presented.